# Ardino-Nano-BLE-Sense "Send Data With Sound" Chirp Project Issue

Tags: arduino, chirp

I am having some issues with the [Send Data with Sound](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ChirpDevs/send-data-with-sound-bf7024?f=1) Project on Arduino. I have my Arduino nano BLE sense, ChirpSDK by Asio Ltd Version 3.4.0 installed, I put in the CHIRP_APP_KEY, CHIRP_APP_SECRET, CHIRP_APP_CONFIG from the chirp website, and I also have the Arduino nano BLE board selected when uploading the code. But for some reason I keep getting this error below:

```
ChirpColor:22:10: error: chirp_connect.h: No such file or directory

 #include "chirp_connect.h"

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
chirp_connect.h: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you check to see that the `chirp_connect.h` was in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK functions have been renamed in the latest release. So `connect` is replaced with `sdk`.

With the latest version, you need to

```
#include "chirp_sdk.h"
```

See the latest header file for the function declarations - https://github.com/chirp/chirp-arduino/blob/develop/src/chirp_sdk.h

Comment: Could you share where you found the documentation related to connect? We can get this updated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code but now I'm getting "PDM.h: No such file or directory" so I was wondering if there is also a PMD.h library that also got changed.

Comment: No PDM.h is a file included by the Arduino Nano 33 BLE board. Make sure you have installed the board from the Boards Manager, and select the board from the menu.